# Customizing JFileChooser with synth

Tags: java, filechooser, synth

I'm having trouble defining a custom style for `JFileChooser` with synth. Simply binding a synth style to `type="region" key="FILE_CHOOSER"` does not work (results in `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.swing.plaf.synth.SynthFileChooserUI.update(Unknown Source), etc. etc. etc.`)

I thought that maybe a `FileChooser` was made up of other standard `JComponent`s, but even when I bind a style to every single `Region` type, I still get the AWT stack dump and the file chooser doesn't display at all.

Additionally, I haven't been able to find a way to customize a `FileChooser` beyond a few simple things like changing the accept/cancel buttons. I want to disable/change other buttons like the "change the way files are displayed" button or the "go up one folder" button.

It seems I may have to make my own `FileChooser`-like GUI element, but I'd rather not. Is there a way to control the built-in one better?

EDIT: I figured out why I wasn't able to override the `JComponent`s present within the `FileChooser`: I was using underscores in my `key`s. But that still leaves the question of how to customize the rest of the buttons in the `FileChooser`. Some parts of the GUI don't even show up at all once a synth style is implemented...

Comment: The JFileChooser is customizable. [Here is a place to start](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074920/learn-java/enterprise-application-integration-customizing-swing-s-file-chooser.html). Just google `modifying the JFileChooser` for more.

Comment: I've read through that article, but it doesn't address the questions that I am asking. And I know how to use Google.